# Bootstrapping dependent data

Tags: p-value, bootstrap, markov-process

I have two vectors say $\{X_t\}$ and $\{Y_t\}$ $(t=1,\ldots,n)$ each are dependent data (from a finite state Markov Chain).

I construct a contingency table from these two (rows are the Markov chain states, columns are whether it is from $X_t$ or $Y_t$). Next I obtain a test statistic I am interested in from this table.

I want to obtain some kind of p-value for my test statistic. My first idea is to use bootstrap, but I am a little unsure how to proceed.

My first idea is to use dependent bootstrap (e.g. Moving Block, Circular Block, or Stationary) on each of $\{X_t\}$ and $\{Y_t\}$ separately, and then for each bootstrap sample (say $\{X_t\}_1,\ldots \{X_t\}_B$ and $\{Y_t\}_1,\ldots \{Y_t\}_B$) construct the contingency table and calculate my test static.

Does this sound reasonable? Am I missing anything obvious? Are there better ways to do this?

Are there better ways to do this utilizing the fact that I have Markov Chains, or that I am using contingency tables?

Comment: So the idea is you have 2 sequences of categories that are temporally ordered & you want to assess if it's reasonable to assume they came from the same data generating process?

Comment: Yes thats right